# Is it possible to introduce extra constraints using e.g. unsafeCoerce?

Tags: haskell, constraints, coercion, unsafe-perform-io

Is it possible to use unsafeCoerce (or some other unsafe functionality) to 'make up' e.g. a Typeable constraint for a type? I.e., to change a type from a `forall v. v` into an existential `forall v. Typeable v => v`?

I am in a situation where I have some datatypes/functions that can handle all types `a` but do require to call `typeOf` and/or `toDyn` on them. The result will not break parametricity, but it is impossible to convince the typechecker of this.

To be precise, I need to convert some types to [`Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) and later back. However, currently the requirement of `Typeable` prevents the implementation of typeclasses such as `Functor`, `Applicative`, etc.

*(I know that [another technique called 'constrained normalized deep embeddings'](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-normal) exists to allow types that require a constraint to still implement these kinds of typeclasses. However, this technique will not work on datatypes containing cycles, as the lowering operation will loop infinitely.)*

So is there a way to convince the typechecker to trust me here? Even if it is very unsafe?

Comment: You might be interested in Sam Derbyshire's work on the [GHC type-checking plugin](https://github.com/sheaf/ghc-tcplugin-api) which allows you to elaborate your own dictionaries

Comment: This question isn't clear enough. Give some concrete examples. Generally speaking, if a type can't contain truely arbitrary elements, then it _shouldn't_ be a functor etc. instance (at least not `Prelude.Functor`). It most definitely is not safe to just improvise those constraints out of thin air using `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: How about https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.13/docs/Data-Constraint-Deferrable.html ?

Comment: The typechecker cannot just "trust you"... The constraint `Typeable a` comes with real runtime data about the type of `a`. You cannot just pull that out of nowhere. Also, you are implementing `Functor`, `Applicative`, etc. for *what*, exactly? It's not `Dynamic` itself, given that it has no type parameter. Please add details to this question about the *actual problem* you are trying to solve, because right now it's very ill-defined.

Comment: Sometimes you can actually get the dictionary you need (e.g., using `withTypeable` if you have the required `TypeRep`, or `reify` if you need a `Reifies` for something in `reflection`). It doesn't sound like you're talking about that, but as @HTNW indicates, it's hard to tell.